# How to find if the value exists in hash without using key in perl?

Tags: perl, hash, hashmap, hashtable

I have an hash map like this

```
my $name = 'AUS'; #dynamic values
my %hash = { 'a'=>{
                  'x'=> {
                         '1' =>'US'
                         '2' =>'UK'
                        }
                  'y'=>{
                          '1' =>'AFRICA'
                          '2' =>'AUS'
                       }
                   }
            'b'=>{
                   'x' =>{
                           '1' =>'US'
                           '2' =>'UK'
                         }
                 }
           };
```

I am trying to find whether name is unique in the hash for each column

```
foreach my $key(keys %hash)
{
   if($name ne $hash{}{}{}) #is name unique in whole hash?
   {
      print "something";
   }
   else
   {
      print "nothing";
   }
}
```

All is fine but when it comes to key 'b' it checks that AUS is not present and prints "something" but I want it to check the 'a' key too to see if has 'AUS' value. So,how to check whether $name exists in whole hash (i can't use find via key-value pair since i am trying to find and print in each column) ?

Comment: That code does not compile.

Comment: @Andrey Use {a}{y}{2} instead of {}{}{} and obvious syntax errors

Comment: Can you show the expected output for both a unique and non-unique key?

Comment: @choroba Just want the $name to be unqiue in the whole hash and since i am checking for each $name in the form i can't do away with foreach loop

Comment: I still don't understand. So you have several @names and you want to check which of them are unique on the third level of the hash reference?

Comment: Why not as you're building this monster of a structure have another hash that tracks what names have already been added?

Comment: I think it's very likely that you've chosen an inappropriate data structure to represent your information. It looks like you have a three-column CSV file that you've dumped into a three-level hash without considering how you will access it. What other operations do you have to perform? Does it make *any* of them straightforward to code?

Comment: @Borodin hats up,i don't know how you guessed that.every assumption of yours is right

Comment: Okay, well why not start with a simple array of arrays and see if you need anything more elaborate. You can write `my @data = map { chomp; [ split /,/ ] } <>` to create that, and it's straightforward to interrogate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $name = 'AUS'; #dynamic values
my %hash = ( 'a'=>{
                  'x'=> {
                         '1' =>'US',
                         '2' =>'UK'
                        },
                  'y'=>{
                          '1' =>'AFRICA',
                          '2' =>'AUS'
                       }
                   },
            'b'=>{
                   'x' =>{
                           '1' =>'US',
                           '2' =>'UK'
                         }
                 }
           );



my @val = grep {$_ eq $name} map {my $x=$_; map {my $y=$_; map {$hash{$x}->{$y}->{$_}} keys %{$hash{$x}->{$_}}} keys %{$hash{$_}}} keys %hash;
if(@val == 0) {
    print "$name not found";
}
elsif(@val == 1) {
    print "$name is unique";
}
else {
    print "$name is not unique";
}
```

Comment: Great solution.But would you be able to generalize? I mean this works fine when there is x,y ,what happens when there's more?

Comment: my $x and my $y are not related to keys of your hashes. Those are just temporary variables. This works fine for x,y,z... as long as there are 3 hash of hashes levels. Sobrique solution works for any number of sublevels.

Comment: Your solution would just do for me,Thanks for helping me out here.I appreciate it

Answer (score 5):

There's no magic bullet here. You have to traverse your hash and inspect each value. There's a variety of approaches to doing this, and which you use is rather dependent on how your hash-source gets populated.

A recursive solution would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;   
my $name = 'AUS';

use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = ( 'a'=>{
                  'x'=> {
                         '1' =>'US',
                         '2' =>'UK'
                        },
                  'y'=>{
                          '1' =>'AFRICA',
                          '2' =>'AUS'
                       }
                   },
            'b'=>{
                   'x' =>{
                           '1' =>'US',
                           '2' =>'UK'
                         }
                 }
           );

my %count_of;

sub traverse {
   my ( $input_hash ) = @_; 
   foreach my $sub ( values %{$input_hash} ) { 
      if (ref $sub) { 
         traverse ($sub);
      }
      else  {
         $count_of{$sub}++;
      }
   }
}

traverse (\%hash); 
print Dumper \%count_of;

print "$name is unique\n" if $count_of{$name} == 1;
```

Because this is recursive, it will walk to any 'depth' of the hash, but that might not be entirely appropriate for you use-case.

However the fact that you're talking about columns, suggests to me that this hash is being populated from elsewhere - I would suggest you look at that population process, because it's quite likely that's a better place to start picking out particular counts-of-values.

If you need a more versatile lookup table:

```
my @unique_elements = grep { $count_of{$_} == 1 } sort keys %count_of;
print Dumper \@unique_elements;
my %is_unique = map { $_ => 1 } @unique_elements; 
print Dumper \%is_unique;

print "$name is unique\n" if $is_unique{$name};
```

Comment: Great solution. Also, you do not need my @values;

Comment: Oh yeah. Did it to populate a list of found elements first time around; I'll remove it.

Comment: The code also gives an error if you are searching for something that does not exist in the hash, which could be easily fixed.