# How to compare two hashes of different levels in perl without using sub routines or modules?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

my arrays are

```
my @arr = ('mars','earth','jupiter');
my @arr1 = ('mercury','mars');
my @arr2 = ('planet','earth','star','sun','planet2','mars');
%space = ( 'earth'=>{
              'planet'=> {
                     '1' =>'US',
                     '2' =>'UK'
                    },
              'planet2'=>{
                      '1' =>'AFRICA',
                      '2' =>'AUS'
                   }
               },
        'sun'=>{
               'star' =>{
                       '1' =>'US',
                       '2' =>'UK'
                     }
             },
        'mars' =>{
                 'planet2' =>{
                               '1' =>'US',
                       '2' =>'UK'
                     }
             }

       );
```

now i am comparing the first two arrays in the following manner

```
foreach (@arr)
{
  $arr_hash{$_} =1;
}
foreach my $name (keys %space)
{
  foreach my $key (keys %{$space{$name}})
  if ($arr_hash{$name} !=1)
  {
    #do something
  }
```

now how should i compare the third array? I am trying something like this

```
  else
  {
     if($arr2_hash{$key}{$name} !=1)
     {
       #do something else
     }
```

I want to check whether the planet+earth pair(ex. the combination of key1 and key2 should be matched with first and second element in @arr2) is present in %space too?
any help?

Comment: This weels like a homework. Similar question was asked yesterday or the day before.

Comment: @Andrey Can you point me in the right direction then? I am really struggling to get this thing going.Does that question that was asked yesterday has answers to my current query?

Comment: The answer that was asked yesterday has similar hash. but the task was different: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701681/how-to-find-if-the-value-exists-in-hash-without-using-key-in-perl

Comment: why do you neeed arr and arr1 if you are comparing arr2 and  %space ?

Comment: I was just letting you know the whole part of what  I am trying to do and the method I wanted to do

Comment: That hash does not compile so this cannot be a working code.

Comment: @Andrey  Go for it now?

Comment: If this is homework, I can understand why no modules. But no subroutines? That's just poor software engineering.

Comment: Well,good for me that i don't have to worry about my coding practices

Comment: @AnaPliskova That's not a good attitude if you're learning to program. If you're just going through the motions... well, it's your life. Professors often teach bad software engineering. Anyhow, are there any restraints on the problem? Is it guaranteed to only be a two level hash containing only scalars? If not, this is a very big problem.

Comment: @Schwern I am sorry if i offended you.well,No restraints.I thought this is a three level hash and the format is guaranteed

Comment: @AnaPliskova Apologies, how programming is taught is a pet peeve of mine and not your fault. Back to the problem. I'm not sure I follow what you're trying to do. Are you trying to check that each pair in `@arr2` exist in `%space`? That `$space{earth}{planet}` and `$space{sun}{star}` and `$space{mars}{planet2}` exist? Were you given these data structures? They're awkward and the problem would be easier if they could be redesigned.

Comment: Yes,just the other way,each pair of %space is present in @arr2. apparently i can't redesign %space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this twice now in Perl. Once for [Test::More's is_deeply()](https://github.com/Test-More/test-more/blob/v0.98/lib/Test/More.pm#L989)  and again for [perl5i's are_equal()](https://github.com/evalEmpire/perl5i/blob/master/lib/perl5i/2/equal.pm). Doing it right is not simple. Doing it without subroutines is just silly. If you want to see how this is done, look at `are_equal()`, though it can be done better.

---

But I don't think you actually need to compare two hashes.

What I think is happening is you need to check if the things in the various arrays are present in `%space`. For example...

```
my @arr = ('mars','earth','jupiter');
```

That would be true, true, and false.

```
my @arr1 = ('mercury','mars');
```

False, true.

```
my @arr2 = ('planet','earth','star','sun','planet2','mars');
```

Assuming these are pairs, they're all true.

I'm going to use better variable names than `@arr` which describe the contents, not the type of the structure. I'm also going to assume that `use strict; use warnings; use v5.10;` is present.

The first two are simple, loop through the array and check if there's an entry in `%space`. And we can do both arrays in one loop.

```
for my $name in (@names1, @names2) {
    print "$name...";
    say $space{$name} ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

The third set is a little trickier, and how the data is laid out makes it harder. Putting pairs in a list is awkward, that's what hashes are for. This would make more sense...

```
my %object_types = (
    earth => "planet", sun => "star", mars => "planet2"
);
```

Then it's easy. Check that `$space{$name}{$type}` is true.

```
for my $name (keys %object_types) {
    my $type = $object_types{$name};

    print "$name / $type...";
    say $space{$name}{$type} ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

Or if you're stuck with the array we can iterate through the list in pairs.

```
# $i will be 0, 2, 4, etc...
for( my $i = 0; $i < $#stellar_objects; $i+=2 ) {
    my($type, $name) = ($stellar_objects[$i], $stellar_objects[$i+1]);

    print "$name / $type...";
    say $space{$name}{$type} ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

What if you had a hash of types with multiple names to check instead?

```
my %object_types = (
    planet =>['earth'],
    star =>['sun'],
    planet2 =>['earth','mars']
);
```

Same idea, but we need an inner loop over the names array. Good use of plural variable names helps keep thing straight.

```
for my $type (keys %object_types) {
    my $names = $object_types{$type};

    for my $name (@$names) {
        print "$name / $type...";
        say $space{$name}{$type} ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
}
```

Since these are really a set of pairs to search for, combining them into a big hash is a disservice. A better data structure to feed this search might be a list of pairs.

```
my @searches = (
    [ planet => 'earth' ],
    [ star => 'sun' ],
    [ planet2 => 'earth' ],
    [ planet2 => 'mars' ],
);

for my $search (@searches) {
    my($type, $name) = @$search;
    print "$name / $type...";
    say $space{$name}{$type} ? "Yes" : "No";
}
```

---

For the record, `%space` is poorly designed. The first two levels are fine, name and type, it's the country hashes that are awkward.

```
'sun'=>{
    'star' =>{
        # This part
        '1' =>'US',
        '2' =>'UK'
    }
},
```

This has none of the advantages of a hash, and all of the disadvantages. The advantage of a hash is it's very fast to look up a single key, but this makes it awkward by making the interesting part a value. If the key is trying to impose an order on the hash, use an array.

```
sun => {
    star => [ 'US', 'UK' ]
},
```

Then you can get a list the countries: `$countries = $space{$name}{$type}`

If you want fast key lookup and order doesn't matter, use a hash with the keys being the thing stored, and the value being 1 (just a placeholder for "true").

```
sun => {
    star => { 'US' => 1, 'UK' => 1 }
},
```

This takes advantage of hash key lookup and allows `$space{$name}{$type}{$country}` to quickly check for existence. The "values" (even though they're stored as keys) are also guaranteed to be unique. This formally known as a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)), a collection of unique values.

And you can store further information in the value.

Comment: and there's a match missing with your %object_types {earth}{planet2}.Assume if your %object_types = (planet =>{'earth'},star =>{'sun'},planet2 =>{'earth','mars'}); how would you check now?

Comment: @AnaPliskova Do you mean each type has a list of names? `%object_types = (planet =>['earth'],star =>['sun'],planet2 =>['earth','mars']);` You'd need an inner loop over the names. I'll edit that in.

Comment: Yes and very neatly explained.You should apply at my school and i hope to learn more

Comment: @AnaPliskova I'm flattered, thank you. :) Edit is up.

Comment: @AnaPliskova You really should accept answers if they solved your problem. :-)

Comment: @NoelWidmer i thought i did,anyway a big thanks to SCHWERN